# How can I replace one text with another with two-way data binding?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mat-table

I covered two cases in Mat-Table. If there is no data, the user sees No Data Found and if he should search in the filter Not Data Found should be hidden and replaced by the entered text. Do you know how this works?

My Code:

```
// Filter input
<input matInput #filter (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Durchsuchen" />

 <!-- Triggered by the filter -->
          <div class="no-search-results" [hidden]="isTableHasData">
            <p>Du hast nach <span class="filter-value">"{{ filter.value }}"</span> gesucht. Wir haben leider keine Ergebnisse gefunden.</p>
          </div>

          <!--  Triggered because there is no data in the backend -->
          <div class="no-data" *ngIf="dataSource !== null && dataSource.data !== null && dataSource.data.length === 0">
            <p>No Data Found</p>
          </div>

// TS
public applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim();
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
    if (this.dataSource.filteredData.length > 0) {
      this.isTableHasData = true;
    } else {
      this.isTableHasData = false;
    }
  }
``
```

Comment: what output do you have in your current code?

Comment: In the current code the text from the first div is displayed when filtering. Which is also correct. Unfortunately I also see the text from the second div. How can I hide it?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no data and the input field used for filtering is empty show the "no data" message. If the table has data but the search result is empty, show the "search term" message.

You can do this using `*ngIf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `If Else` here like this to show only the table if there's a data and if not, show your no data message.

```
  <div *ngIf="dataSource !== null && dataSource.data !== null && dataSource.data.length === 0; else noData" class="no-search-results">
            <p>Du hast nach <span class="filter-value">"{{ filter.value }}"</span> gesucht. Wir haben leider keine Ergebnisse gefunden.</p>
          </div>
  <ng-template #noData>
          <div class="no-data">
            <p>No Data Found</p>
          </div>

  </ng-template>
```

Check this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-filter-predicate-zs7bgd?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.html

Comment: Hello, thanks for your example. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I want if there is no data and the user uses the filter no-data is not shown and you only see no-search-results.

Here is my code snippet: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-filter-predicate-zdbgqn?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.html

Comment: not really sure what you meant. could you explain it in a better way? ;)

Comment: What I'm trying to do... If there is no data in the table you see Not Found. If the user enters something in the filter, only what he enters should be displayed and Not Found should be hidden. This does not work... see stackblitz

Comment: @anyanx check my updated answer. i also updated the stackblitz. hope that's what you're looking for

Comment: In your example Not Data Found is not displayed